# Ubuntu 16.04 won't power off: poweroff.target is disabled

Tags: 16.04, shutdown

Ubuntu 16.04 won't power off. When I go to the icon at the top right of the screen and click shutdown, it does not shutdown. I ran `shutdown -h now` and this is what I got:

```
tanner@tanner-x151x:~$ shutdown -h now
Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to power off system via logind: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to start poweroff target: Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status poweroff.target' for details. 
Failed to open /dev/initctl: Permission denied 
Failed to talk to init daemon. 
tanner@tanner-x151x:~$ sudo shutdown -h now 
[sudo] password for tanner: 
Failed to start poweroff target: Transaction is destructive. 
5ee system logs and 'systemctl status poweroff.target' for details.
tanner@tanner-x151x:~$ sudo halt now
Too many arguments. 
tanner@tanner-x151x:~$ systemctl status poweroff.target
  poweroff.target - Power-off
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/poweroff.target; disabled; vendor preset:
   Active: inactive (dead) 
   Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
```

I have no  idea why this is happening or how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you already tried `sudo shutdown -P now`? I know that is almost the same thing as -h, but with command this I've never got problem.

Comment: This "Transaction is destructive" message sounds interesting. What does `systemctl status poweroff.target` say at this point?

Comment: @Jos i honestly can not find this file.

Comment: It is a command. Just at the terminal enter `systemctl status poweroff.target`.

Comment: i entered it and this is what i got                                                                                                                'tanner@tanner-X751LX:~$ systemctl status poweroff.target
● poweroff.target - Power-Off
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/poweroff.target; disabled; vendor preset:
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd.special(7)'

Comment: sudo shutdown -h now

Comment: @ValeriySolovyov already tried that.

Comment: what is output of `systemctl status poweroff.target` or `journalctl -xn`?

Comment: the out put of systemctl status poweroff.target is      poweroff.target - Power-Off Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/poweroff.target; disabled; vendor preset: Active: inactive (dead) Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

Comment: i updated my post 2nd picture is what i get when I run  'systemctl status poweroff.target'

Comment: I still have this issue too. Any news?

Comment: Does `poweroff` work for you?

Comment: It has been reported: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1441253

Comment: There's a similar issue to your and have answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/788559/83345

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't shutdown xubuntu after updating to 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/761189/cant-shutdown-xubuntu-after-updating-to-16-04)

Comment: I have this problem too. sudo shutdown -P now also gives "Requested transaction contradicts existing jobs: Transaction is destructive."

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit brutal, but you can try:

> sudo poweroff -f

Answer credit belongs here: https://askubuntu.com/a/788559/580637

Answer (score 4):

The issue should be solved by entering this command to enable the systemd service of "poweroff.target":

```
systemctl enable poweroff.target
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. :(

Comment: Didn't work for me either