# Systemd, reboot and permissions

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, root, reboot, systemd

Since I am new and cannot comment on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764565/ubuntu-16-04-wont-power-off-poweroff-target-is-disabled?newreg=5649b1a0665f49e9a5f09336b700afb3) yet, I'll open a new question...

The question is about `Systemd/Systemctl` not allowing one to shutdown or reboot.

The answer I wanted to comment on is saying that you can simply type:

```
systemctl enable poweroff.target
```

to resolve the issue.
This however, at least on my system, does not work.

As you can see in the below attempt, I was logged in (sudo su) to root, and even root isn't allowed to reboot:

```
root@Vidar:/home/bokkie# systemctl enable poweroff.target
root@Vidar:/home/bokkie# shutdown -r now
Failed to start reboot.target: Transaction is destructive.
See system logs and 'systemctl status reboot.target' for details.
root@Vidar:/home/bokkie#
```

The only option I seem to have to reboot is to do a hard (longer power button press) shutdown.

Can I replace systemd, or somehow convince systemctl that shutting down/rebooting is allowed? If yes, how?

Comment: Is this Ubuntu 14.04? Then the way to shut it down is `sudo shutdown -p now`. Your running `systemd` which is for Ubuntu 16.04 and above

Comment: I'd love for the answer to be so simple...

root@Vidar:/home/bokkie# shutdown --help
[...]
  -H --halt      Halt the machine
  -P --poweroff  Power-off the machine
  -r --reboot    Reboot the machine
[...]
root@Vidar:/home/bokkie# shutdown -P now
[...]
root@Vidar:/home/bokkie# 

I don't want to power off. I want to reboot. And no, it's still not working...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by simple, but `systemctl` doesn't exist on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 16.04

```
systemctl enable poweroff.target
```

creates a symlink at `/etc/systemd/system/ctrl-alt-del.target` which changes the behaviour of hitting ctrl+alt+delete to poweroff instead of reboot

To reboot using `systemctl` you should run

```
systemctl isolate reboot.target
```

If you really need to reboot and nothing seems to work, there is an alternative way. This is pretty similar to holding the poweroff button, but I don't recommend using this unless it's a last resort. You can run:

```
echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

which will immediately reboot without doing anything (including unmounting filesystems) - which can cause filesystem corruption etc. More details can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) and [here](http://blog.kember.net/articles/reisub-the-gentle-linux-restart/).

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274761/bunsenlabs-debian-derrivative-wont-shut-down-failed-to-start-poweroff-target) may also be useful.

Comment: Powering off is easy, the power button will do just fine. I want to reboot... ;-)

root@Vidar:/home/bokkie# systemctl isolate reboot.target
Failed to start reboot.target: Transaction is destructive.
See system logs and 'systemctl status reboot.target' for details.
root@Vidar:/home/bokkie# 

back to square one: destructive transaction, reboot.target being disabled/dead... as per the post I linked.

Comment: I'd like to know why the transaction is destructive...
So that I may prevent it from becoming destructive again.
I'd also like to tell systemd to shove it...

Comment: If you want to remove systemd have a look at http://without-systemd.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_remove_systemd_from_an_Ubuntu_Xenial_installation

Answer (score 0):

It worked, after I entered my password for access to my encrypted home dir...
I looked at syslog just before trying again, and found:

```
Sep 25 14:57:14 Vidar systemd[1]: message repeated 3 times: [ Requested transaction contradicts existing jobs: Transaction is destructive.]
Sep 25 14:57:22 Vidar systemd-cryptsetup[25670]: Loading of cryptographic parameters failed: Invalid argument
Sep 25 14:57:22 Vidar systemd-cryptsetup[25670]: Failed to activate: Invalid argument
Sep 25 14:57:23 Vidar systemd[1]: systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap1.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 25 14:57:23 Vidar systemd[1]: Failed to start Cryptography Setup for cryptswap1.
Sep 25 14:57:23 Vidar systemd[1]: Dependency failed for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device.
Sep 25 14:57:23 Vidar systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1.
Sep 25 14:57:23 Vidar systemd[1]: dev-mapper-cryptswap1.swap: Job dev-mapper-cryptswap1.swap/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 25 14:57:23 Vidar systemd[1]: dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device: Job dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 25 14:57:23 Vidar systemd[1]: systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap1.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 25 14:57:23 Vidar systemd[1]: systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap1.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I'll close this question.